# increase Android BLE bonding / pairing dialog timeout

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-ble, pairing

I have an android app that connects to a BLE device and pairs with it using `BleDevice.createBond()`. the issue is that the dialog could disappear before the user noticing it.

here is a screenshot of the dialog I am talking about.

[image]

how long does the dialog appear? the documentation doesn't mention it

is there any way to increase the time of which the dialog is showing?

Comment: What dialog are you referring to? The one showing the passkey or some other dialog?

Comment: @Emil I updated the question and added a screenshot, please check again.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot increase the time.
The dialog can only be valid for 30 seconds (even shorter if you also have to enter a PIN)
this is because of BLE_GAP_SEC_STATUS_TIMEOUT and is defined in the Bluetooth Core Spec as 30 seconds (Bluetooth Specification, Version 5.0, Vol 3, Part H, Section 3.4 - SMP Timeout.)